# Why does this plot correspond to this function?

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, 2d

I have a function:

$$
u_1(\mathbf{x})=
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if} \;\;|x_1|\le r_1, |x_2| \le r_2 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
,\mathbf{x}=[x_1,x_2]^T \in \mathbb{R}^2
$$

And I'm told that if $r_{1}=r_{2}=5$, then plotting it in Matlab with `stem3` should look like this:

[image]

Maybe I'm just too exhausted at this point, but I don't see how this is the same function. It looks like it's equal to 1 between 10 and 20 rather than between -5 and 5? Can someone please explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally, you are correct. But the question says "should look like this". And not "should be equal too". Apparently, the graph drawn is just a hint of the solution, and one should correctly set the $x$- and $y$-axis markers to get the actual solution, only a shift away with the vector $(-15,-15)$, that could replace this graph based on a $[0,30]^2$ grid. Try:

```
x = [-15:1:15];
y = x;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
z = (abs(X)<=5) .* (abs(Y)<=5);
figure(1);
subplot(1,2,1)
stem3(z);axis tight
subplot(1,2,2)
stem3(x,y,z);axis tight
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The axes in your plot seem to be indexes into an array, as if you were using `stem3(Z)` instead of `stem3(X,Y,Z)`.

Check the example [in the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stem3.html).